# CSS - 4 <td>'s to 2 <td>'s when screen size changes

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have this table which is just one table row (`<tr>`) which contains 4 `<td>` elements. When the screen size changes to below 768px, I would like to spread out those 4 `<td>`'s over two "rows", each row containing two `<td>` elements...

How would I go to do this? I tried giving each `<td>` a width of 50% and then float left, but that gives me a single row for each `<td>` with some white space left till the border of the table...

```
<table id="tabel1" cellspacing="0" width="1000px">
    <tr>
        <td width="25%">Laurens Mäkel</td>
        <td width="25%">Mozartlaan 15</td> 
        <td width="25%">8031 AA</td>
        <td width="25%">97039259@example.com</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: post a [mcve] with the CSS and HTML It should be easy

Comment: If I were you. I'll use javascript. Advantages are browser support, dynamic and you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Flexbox is a good route to go down

Comment: Neither JavaScript or flexbox are needed.. supposed to do this with css and tables...

Comment: Try to override table behavior first. Goodluck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

below is a snippet using `<table>` and `display:inline-block`.
`margin-left:-4px` is to fix the problem  of extra space between two `inline-block` element.

```css
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  #tabel1{
    width:90%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  #tabel1 td{
    display:inline-block;
    width:50%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  #tabel1 td:nth-child(3){
    clear:both;
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="tabel1" cellspacing="0" width="1000px" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Look what this does.... The whitespace at the right side, and this doesn't put 2 next to each other... https://snag.gy/ZEqPhc.jpg

Comment: Thanks alot, this sent me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 2):

Better this make through flex-box

```css
.table {
  display: flex;
}

.table .col {
  width: 25%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 786px) {
  .table {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .table .col {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
<div class="col">COL</div>
<div class="col">COL</div>
<div class="col">COL</div>
<div class="col">COL</div>
</div>
```

JsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/grinmax_/avav3dLs/

Comment: Thank you but I'm supposed to do this with tables for a school assignment.